# no match for ‘operator* for instances

Tags: c++, pointers, llvm, yacc, llvm-ir

I am trying to generate a code for a certain language using bison, flex and llvm.
Here is part of the code(the dots refer to code not related to the question) for the union and the rules section :

```
%union {
    Node *node;
    NBlock *block;
    NMethodCall* methodcall;
    .
    .
    .
    std::vector<NIdentifier*> idetListvec;
    std::vector<NRecordItem*> recdListvec;
    .
    .

}
.
.
type           <expr>              numeric      
%type           <expr>              CondExpression
%type           <idetListvec>       IdentifierList
%type           <recdListvec>       RecordItemList  VarDefnList FormalParmSecList   VarDefns FormalParameterList

.
.
%%
.
.

FormalParameterList :  TLPAREN FormalParmSecList  TRPAREN  {$$ = $2;}
                    ;

FormalParmSecList : FormalParmSecList  TSEMICOLON   FormalParmSec   { $1->push_back($3);}
                  | FormalParmSec                                   {$$ = new NRecordItemList(); $$->push_back($1);}
                  ;


FormalParmSec : ValueParmSpec                                       {$$ = $1;}
              | VariableParmSpec                                    {$$ = $1;}
              ;

%%
```

I had a separate file for the so called Abstract Syntax Tree(AST) for implementing the classes. The following is the class I want to ask about:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class NStatement;
.
classNRecordItem;
classModule;
.
.
typedef std::vector<NRecordItem*> NRecordItemList;
typedef std::vector<NConstantDeclaration*> NConstantDeclarationList;
typedef std::vector<NTypDefn> NTypDefnList;
typedef std::vector<Module> NModuleList;

class Node {
public:
    virtual ~Node() {}
    //virtual llvm::Value* codeGen(CodeGenContext& context) { return NULL; }
};


class NExpression : public Node {
};

class NStatement : public Node {
};

class NInteger : public NExpression {
public:
    int value;
    NInteger(int value) : value(value) { }
    //virtual llvm::Value* codeGen(CodeGenContext& context);
};
.
.
class NRecordItem : public NStatement {
public:
    const NIdentifier& type;
    NIdentifierList arguments;
    NRecordItem(NIdentifierList& arguments, const NIdentifier& type ) :
        type(type),  arguments(arguments) { }
    //virtual llvm::Value* codeGen(CodeGenContext& context);
};
```

when running the code, it gives me the following error:

```
parser.y:256:26: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<NRecordItem*>’ and ‘NRecordItemList* {aka int*}’)
                   | FormalParmSec         {$$ = new NRecordI
                          ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:69:0,
                 from node.h:2,
                 from parser.y:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc:167:5: note: candidate: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = NRecordItem*; _Alloc = std::allocator<NRecordItem*>]
     vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc:167:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘NRecordItemList* {aka int*}’ to ‘const std::vector<NRecordItem*>&’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:64:0,
                 from node.h:2,
                 from parser.y:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:448:7: note: candidate: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&&) [with _Tp = NRecordItem*; _Alloc = std::allocator<NRecordItem*>]
       operator=(vector&& __x) noexcept(_Alloc_traits::_S_not
       ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:448:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘NRecordItemList* {aka int*}’ to ‘std::vector<NRecordItem*>&&’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:470:7: note: candidate: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(std::initializer_list<_Tp>) [with _Tp = NRecordItem*; _Alloc = std::allocator<NRecordItem*>]
       operator=(initializer_list<value_type> __l)
       ^
```

My question is about the rule 'FormalParmSecList'. I stored the value of the paramters in a vector class but it gives that error.
any idea !

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to put `std::vector` objects *directly* in your `%union`.  That's not going to work, as they are not going to be constructed and destructed properly.  You need to change your `%union` to use pointers:

```
%union {
    :
    std::vector<NIdentifier*> *idetListvec;
    std::vector<NRecordItem*> *recdListvec;
```

You're already trying to store pointers to the vectors in your actions, so it looks like you were trying to do this already, you just missed the declaration.

Comment: I will post the whole of my code .. There are are a lot of similar errors because of that .. I do not know how to solve the problem

Comment: You are correct but I have no sufficient reputations.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$$ = new NRecordItemList();
```

This statement creates a pointer to a `NRecordItemList` object and assigns it to `$$`. However, somewhere you declared that `$$` is a `NRecordItemList`, not a pointer to one. You either need to remove `new` from this statement or change the type declaration for this grammar rule so that `$$` has the correct type. I don't see where you declared the type for this particular rule in the code you posted here. You need to find this and fix it. (It has also been a while since I used bison.)

Comment: $$ refers to FormalParmSecList which is of type std::vector<NRecordItem*> . It  is defined : %type    <recdListvec> FormalParmSecList. where 'recdListvec' is declared in the %union section like : std::vector<NRecordItem*> recdListvec; .  it is a pointer right?

Comment: @rationalrose: `std::vector<NRecordItem*>` is a vector of pointers to items. `std::vector<NRecordItem>*` is a pointer to a vector of items. `std::vector<NRecordItem*>*` is a pointer to a vector of pointers to items. Since a `std::vector` cannot be a member of a union, you want either the second or the third, probably the second.

Comment: @RationalRose `std::vector<NRecordItem*>` is a vector of pointers but is not itself a pointer. You probably need `std::vector<NRecordItem*>*` or equivalently `NRecordItemList*`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a `std::vector` with a pointer to a `std::vector` (aka `std::vector*`).

Remove the `new` from the error line to get `{$$ = NRecordItemList(); $$->push_back($1)}`

Comment: That's not going to work, as `$$` likely contains random garbage, not a valid constructed `std::vector`.  You need something like `new (&$$) NRecordItemList();`, bvut that still doesn't handle destruction properly.